# Angularjs : ng-model wont read the exact input value if value is changes using jquery val() function

Tags: angularjs

I have issues about angularjs binding when i add data to input field using val() function.

my input looks like this

```
<input id="input" type="text" ng-model="data" />
```

and i have a checkbox that add "Hello World" string to input field if checked. so i coded it like this

```
$('#checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('#input').val("Hello World");
    }
});
```

but seems ng-model not working because its not binding the "Hello World" to my controller. can someone helps me on this? thank you. .

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you not to mix jquery with angular you can do it with angular only something like

**Html**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" ng-change="myFunction()" ng-model="isChecked">

<input id="input" type="text" ng-model="data" />
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.myFunction=function(){
if($scope.isChecked){
$scope.data="hello world";
}
}
```